# What uses can and should philosophy be put to?

Tags: politics, education, philosophy-of-political-science, discourse

Philosophy seems to underpin many of our activities, such as politics. So is philosophy active or reactive? Is philosophy a force for good?

Comment: Vague questions get vague answers. - Please elaborate a bit more on your questions, give some context and employ clear cut concepts.

Comment: For vague read fundamental?

Comment: No, why do you think that? One can make efforts to formulate fundamental questions by using clear cut concepts.

Comment: i disagree and don't think the question is "vague" @JoWehler no more than any other really. it would be better fleshed out, that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Philosophy is certainly a force and it is leading where people behind it are leading it. A knife is a tool or a weapon based on it's usage; sometimes though, you can cut yourself.